# spring + angular pagination

Tags: angular, spring, pagination

I'm using REST service to get data for my table:

```
@RequestMapping(value=("/demandes"))
    public Page<AttestationTravail> listEtudiants(int page, int size){
        return attRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
    }
```

I'm displaying it with angular as a client:
html for pagination:

```
<ul *ngIf="pages" class="nav nav-pills ">
                <li  class="nav-item"  *ngFor="let p of pages; let i= index">
                  <a class="nav-link clickable" [ngClass]=" i ==currentPage? 'active' : ''" (click)="onPageAttestation(i)">{{i}}</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

My .ts:

```
loadAttestations(){
    this.attServie.getPages(this.currentPage,this.size).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.totalPages=data.totalPages;
      this.pages= new Array<number>(this.totalPages);
      this.attestations= data['content'];
    });
  }
```

result :

[image]

if works but my problem is if I have 200 pages it will display 200 number, is there a way to make the numbers' list contains only three numbers at once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the whole logic and used ngx-pagination instead and it solved the problem.
also changed the rest service to return a list .

tutorial link:
https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-6-pagination-implement-local-or-server-pagination-in-3-steps/